# Bootstrap 5 display property on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, bootstrap-5, display

I have two cols with classes

```
<div class="col-2 d-none d-md-block">
```

and top bar with class

```
<div class="d-md-none">
```

It works on desktop, but on mobile devices doesn't

Bootstrap 5

I tried to add `display: none !important;`